# Java bit shift strange results

Tags: java

I have the following number:
*100000100000001*

I use the following method to get bits that are 1s:

```
long number=100000100000001;

 for(int i=0;i<=15;i++)
        if ((( number>>> i) & 1) != 0)
          //if ((number.shiftRight(i).and(new BigInteger("1"))).intValue() != 0)
        {

          LogMessage("Bit 1: "+i);
        }
```

I get this:

> Bit 1: 0
>
> Bit 1: 8
>
> Bit 1: 13

It is clearly wrong.

I tried it with BigInteger, the same result.

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: `long number=100000100000001` is not in base 2, it is in base 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
long number = 0b100000100000001;
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the downvote, though. It is a fair question, some people could run into this.

Comment: People probably downvote because your question "does not show any research effort". Since you know about bit operations you should also know about the default base of an `int` being 10, not 2.

Comment: Well, I also know how to operate a car, yet I definitely don't know what kind of parts are inside the gearbox (probably gears that roll counterclockwise...or clockwise...). I was doing some effort but in the wrong direction.

Comment: No offense, I was just guessing about the downvotes.

Comment: None taken, I appreciate your answer.